# After renaming workspace in Eclipse the full workspace path stays the same

Tags: eclipse, workspace

I renamed my workspace in Eclipse from 'codewars' to 'tdd'. When I try to switch workspaces, the old name still shows. When I go to options the full workspace path shows the old path: '/Users/marcinkulik/git/codewars' and I am unable to change it as the area is greyed out. How can I change full workspace path without breaking anything?

[image]

Comment: The workspace cannot be moved (some plug-ins uses absolute paths in `<workspace>/.metadata`, e. g. for caching). But you can create a new workspace via _File > Switch Workspace_ (check the _Copy Settings_ check boxes) and then import the projects from the old workspace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the folder name in Finder(Mac) from 'codewars' to 'tdd'. It does seem to be working fine now. Now when I want to switch workspace in Eclipse I can choose '/Users/marcinkulik/git/tdd' workspace.